# Assigning self in init to a different pointer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, automatic-ref-counting

Are there any implication, when i don't assign self to it's super init, but to a completely different pointer, even a Static one? Will arc behave correctly? what are the implications of such an action?

```
static NSObject * StaticObject;

- (instancetype)init {

    self = StaticObject;
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

ARC will behave just fine. You'll have a problem initialising StaticObject. You could do something like

```
if (StaticObject == nil) {
    self = [super init];
    StaticObject = self;
} else {
    self = StaticObject;
}
```

I would think that the NSNull class does something like that.

Assuming that StaticObject isn't nil and has been initialised, you will cause confusion if you modify StaticObject, since others might be holding a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is safe. I think you will be leaking the memory of the original self, and potentially later on over-releasing your singleton. ARC isn't magic, it just sneaks in retain/release calls in the caller and your logic probably never lets ARC see the result of the alloc call.